# Creating a view that shows the balance of accounts on every day, when the "balance" table only has entries on those days where the balance changes

Tags: sql, date, join

I have 2 tables that I need to join in a specific way.
"Date" is a one-column table that simply shows every day from 1990 to 2040.
"Balance" has the balance of hundreds of bank accounts. The trick: Only when the balance of an account changes does the database create a new entry for that account in "Balance". Once the account has a new balance, an new entry is created. There are no entries for the days where the balance stayed the same.

Now I need to create a view that shows the balance of all accounts on every day. That means that I have to show the dates from "Dates" and a corresponding balance of every account. When I join the two tables, on a given day I only see those accounts that changed on that day, I don't get to see the balance of accounts that haven't changed. How do I fix this?

"Dates"

```
Date

1.1.1990  
2.1.1990  
3.1.1990
```

"Balance"

```
  Date      Account     Balance  

  1.1.1990    1             100
  1.1.1990    2              60
  1.1.1990    3               0
  2.1.1990    2              50
  3.1.1990    1             150
```

Desired Result

```
  Date      Account     Balance  
  1.1.1990    1             100
  1.1.1990    2              60
  1.1.1990    3               0
  2.1.1990    1             100
  2.1.1990    2              50
  2.1.1990    3               0
  3.1.1990    1             150
  3.1.1990    2              50
  3.1.1990    3               0
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? This can easily be done using a window function and a "running sum".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to provide more correct query, if you'll provide description for tables and some sample data. However, I think this query would work - it'll return the closest to given date row from BALANCE:

```
SELECT * FROM DATES d, BALANCE b
WHERE d.date >= b.date
      AND b.date >= ALL (SELECT b1.date FROM BALANCE b1
                    WHERE b1.date <= d.date
                          AND b1.account = b.account)
```

---

This query should provide the desired result:

```
SELECT d.date, b.account, b.balance FROM DATES d, BALANCE b
WHERE d.date >= b.date
      AND b.date >= ALL (SELECT b1.date FROM BALANCE b1
                         WHERE b.account = b1.account
                               AND d.date >= b1.date)
ORDER BY d.date, b.account
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I added some sample data and a sample of the desired result.

Comment: @user2463153 Edited an answer, the new query should work just fine.

Comment: your answer seems to work. Can you please explain to me the logic behind this query?

Comment: @user2463153 This query takes every possible combination of rows of tables DATES and BALANCE where date value from balance is earlier than the one from dates, after that it leaves only rows, where for each given account and given date from DATES the date from BALANCE is the closest below to the DATES value.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach should be the following, where DATES is the dates table with D as the date attribute and BALANCE is the balance table with attributes BAL_DATE for the balance date and AMOUNT for the current balance:

```
SELECT SUB.D, B.AMOUNT
FROM (
    SELECT D.D AS D,MAX(B.BAL_DATE) AS BD
    FROM DATES D, BALANCE B
    WHERE D.D>=B.BAL_DATE
    GROUP BY D.D) AS SUB, BALANCE B
WHERE SUB.BD = B.BAL_DATE
ORDER BY SUB.D
```

The SUB subquery matches all dates rows with the balance rows having date less or equal to the corresponding date row and for each date row takes the balance row with max date, i. e. the most recent balance or the current if the two dates are equal.
The purpose of the outer main query is to get the corresponding amount for each single date.

Comment: thank you. your query is much faster than the one above, however the result is not what I need. I don't know why, but lots of dates are missing in the result.

Comment: Are those dates from the dates table or from the balance one?